# How to get a Docker container's IP address from the Windows host

Tags: docker

How do I detect the IP of a docker container running on Windows host with WSL?

I can see docker container is running:

```
juergen@DESKTOP4WIN10:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                  NAMES
74f26c50a729   jschulze71/apache2   "sh -c '. /etc/apach…"   24 seconds ago   Up 23 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   elegant_jepsen
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever need this IP address; I'd be a little surprised if it worked.  It looks like you correctly used a `docker run -p 8080:80` option and you should be able to access `http://localhost:8080`.  Why do you need an IP address here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Open Windows command line and use *ipconfig*

```
ipconfig
```

Find *Ethernet-Adapter vEthernet (WSL)* (Or similar) there you will see IP4 and IP6.

Screenshot is from a german Windows but I am sure other version look pretty much the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try launching "hostname -I" command inside the running container.
For example:

```
docker exec -ti <container_id> /bin/bash -c "hostname -I"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IP address of containers from this command:

```
docker inspect -f "{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}" <container_name_or_id>
```